# Get specific index of value in python start with 1

Tags: python, indexing

```
def print_factors(x):
    arr = []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            arr.append(i)
    for index, value in enumerate(arr, start = 1):
        print(index, value)

num = 10
print_factors(num)

Output :
1 1
2 2
3 5
4 10
```

Now I want specific index value.
Example:
enter 3, output will be 5;
enter 4, output will be 10;

Please help to clear my logic.

Comment: you need to be more specific here

Comment: List indices start with 0. If a 1-based index is entered, you have to subtract 1 to get the internal 0-based index for list. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question...

```
def get_factors(x):
    arr = []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            arr.append(i)
    return arr

factors = get_factors(10)
num = 4
print(num, factors[num-1])
```

more sophisticated ...

```
def get_factors(x):
    return [i for i in range(1, x+1) if x % i == 0]

factors = get_factors(10)
num = 4
print(num, factors[num-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to enter an index to check the value from the array, just return the array so you can get the values. We can enter any index we want from the array to get the value.

```
def print_factors(x):
    arr = []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            arr.append(i)
    #print(arr)
    for index, value in enumerate(arr, start = 1):
        print(index, value)
    return arr

num = 10
arr = print_factors(num)
print(arr[2]) # what is index 2!
```

This might be a better way to write this. Have a function that builds the array, and another that can print the factors and the index

```
def build_factors(x):
    arr = []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            arr.append(i)
    return arr

def print_factors(arr):
    for index, value in enumerate(arr, start = 1):
        print(index, value)

num = 10
arr_factors = build_factors(num)

print_factors(arr_factors)
print(arr_factors[2]) # what is index 2!
```